# How to read large Excel file into single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file of 600k rows. how to read it into single dataframe using `pd.read_excel()`? I can't convert excel file into csv as file contains multiple sheets.

is there any dynamic solution as rows can be increased in future.

Comment: How should the multiple sheets be combined in the output dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
# Read all worksheets from an Excel file
xlsx = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
# Concatenate all worksheets into a single DataFrame
df = pd.concat(xlsx, ignore_index=True)
```

Hope this helps you